# Error in plugin solidity-coverage: TypeError: provider.send is not a function - Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solidity-coverage

In case you ever get this error

> `Error in plugin solidity-coverage: TypeError: provider.send is not a function`
> when trying to run coverage for your solidity contracts. Do the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make sure your hardhat version is >= v"^2.11.0". if not change it in your `package.json` to `"hardhat": "^2.11.0"` or higher then run  `npm i`

> Then update your `solidity-coverage` version to the highest => `0.8.0` or higher depending on when you're seeing this. the error was fixed in the 0.8.0 versions.

hope this helps.
-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to solve it by downgrading hardhat from version 2.16.1 to 2.14.1 via `npm i hardhat@2.14.1`.

Comment: Good to see I wasn't the only one. lol